# How to set equal row height in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have json data file which has different size of item and rows size showing according to json data but I want to equal row size in `RecyclerView`.

How to achieve that I found only for `GridLayoutManager` only but its not meet my requirement, any help?

```
public class UserMsgAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserMsgAdpater.MyViewHolder> {
public ArrayList<UserMessage> selected_usersList=new ArrayList<>();
private List<UserMessage> userList;
Context ctx;

TextView textview;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public UserMsgAdpater(Context context, List<UserMessage> data,ArrayList<UserMessage> selectedList) {
   this. userList = data;
   this. ctx = context;
   this.selected_usersList = selectedList;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView userName;
    public CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_temp);
    }
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.user_temp_list, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.userName.setText(userList.get(position).getMessage());

    holder.itemView
            .setBackgroundColor(mSelectedItemsIds.get(position) ?Color.GRAY
                    : Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//Put or delete selected position into SparseBooleanArray
public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//Get total selected count
public int getSelectedCount() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}

//Return all selected ids
public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public UserMessage get(int i) {
    return userList.get(i);
}}
```

in my activity I'm using this code for item decoration please look at that.

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacingItemDecoration(16,EqualSpacingItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: One workaround would be to use a `GridLayoutManager` with only one column.

Comment: Can you attach the screen shot of your current output?

Comment: i used  linear layout manger for that and text view data size is different so row size expend according to data, but i need to fix it.

Comment: Please attach the ss so that we can get a better idea what is happening

Comment: ok, i tied to upload

Comment: why dont you set textview maximum lines or set particular height to main layout  ?

Comment: i did not found any way to attach screen shot,the problem is that the i want to rows size should fix the row size not expend account to json data size, like if data having 1 message the row size ok, but if message has multiple line the row size should be equal to upper size row.

Comment: @Bunny can you elaborate that.

Comment: @ashish if i am not wrong ..you want to fix the row size ,so try to set maximum lines( android:maxLines="1") property to textview in your xml (user_temp_list) ...it will solve your problem

Comment: @Bunny i tried that.

Comment: Remove itemDecorations from your recyclerview. And give your row layout a fixed height in the xml

Comment: please show your xml

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_temp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Msg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

Comment: @Bunny i have just on textview that it.

Comment: please add max lines="1".if this doesnt work add parent layout  with particular height  and set textview inside that layout it will work for sure.

Comment: @Bunny its working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of each item inside your **ViewHolder constructor**:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mHeight); 
itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where mHeight is an integer value of the desired item height.

For your code it'll look like this:

```
private int mHeight = 100;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView userName;
    public CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_temp);

        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mHeight);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
}
```